# real eigenvalues for non normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is there unbounded non normal operator in Hilbert space which has only real eigenvalues?

If yes, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Take the direct sum of two copies of $\ell^2$. On the first copy, the operator will be a shift (not normal, no eigenvalues). On the second copy, it will be an unbounded operator with real eigenvalues, for example $(x_n)\mapsto (n x_n)$. The direct sum has all the required properties.